# How can I remove an Application Pool in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, application-pool

I use `SharePoint 2013` and I create `Secure Store Service App` and remove it.

When I want create this Service Application with the same Pool Name I get this error :

```
This Server Application Pool already exist....
```

How can I remove an Application Pool in SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/wkng/archive/2012/10/19/deleting-unused-application-pool-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx) that also works for Share point 2013.

according to that, we can do this :

1. Launch the SharePoint 2010 Management Shell with administrator privileges 
   (Start -> All Programs -> Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Products -> Right click on SharePoint 2010 Management Shell -> Run as administrator).
2. Run 'Get-SPServiceApplicationPool'.
3. Run 'Get-SPServiceApplicationPool -Identity <"Name of the application pool">
4. Run ‘Remove-SPServiceApplicationPool’.
5. Input the Identity <"Name of the application pool">.
6. Input 'Y' to delete the application pool.